# SUPEE-8788 magento 1.7.0.0 upload image button not responding after patch

Tags: magento-1.7, backend, patches, image-upload, supee-8788

I am having an issue with image upload on backend after apply patch 8788.

I have seen problems with upload image but this I believe is different as upload file doesnt trigger any action or display any error.

Basically buttons 'upload file' and 'remove' dont work, not firing any function, just do nothing.

I can browse file and select a file and open. After that I can see the image ready to upload.

[image]

But as I said upload and remove buttons do not respond.

I cant see any issue on server or php issue, only issue I see is js on console:

[image]

Things I have tried:

-Cache is cleared, even minifycache.

-all permissions on js and media. group is also apache group.

-Checked that modifications are made, patch was applied successfully.

-js files are present (instance.js, browser.js, flow.min.js, fusty-flow.js, fusty-flow-factory.js...)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I also notice that the product I am showing on the screenshot has 4 images. none of them are being displayed. But they are present on frontend

Comment: After installing patch just clear magento cache, browser cache and relogin . It will solve your problem.

Comment: Already made, cleared all magento cache, browser cache and removed cache from server, issue still present